# Web scraping Trulia with Pythons Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the trulia estimate for a given address. Although some addresses do not have a trulia estimate. So I want to first try to find the text 'Trulia estimate' and if it is found then I will try to find the value. At the moment I cannot figure out how to find the Trulia Estimate text which is shown here:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')
def get_trulia_estimate(address):
    driver.get('https://www.trulia.com/')
    print(address)
    element = (By.ID, 'homepageSearchBoxTextInput')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).send_keys(address)
    search_button = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-auto-test-id='searchButton']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(search_button)).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find('div', {'class', 'Text__TextBase-sc-1cait9d-0 OmRik'})
    print(results)

get_trulia_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651')
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version using `beautifulsoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.trulia.com/json/search/location/?query={}&searchType=for_sale'
search_string = '693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

d = requests.get(url.format(search_string), headers=headers).json()
property_url = 'https://www.trulia.com' + d['url']

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(property_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('h3:has(+div span:contains("Trulia Estimate"))').text)
```

Prints:

```
$1,735,031
```

The CSS Selector `h3:has(+div span:contains("Trulia Estimate"))` finds `<h3>` that has tag `<div>` containing `<span>` with string "Trulia Estimate" as direct sibling.

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: grate answer! for `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CSS is generated every time...

I recommend using XPATH for this...

Use `.text` to get the text.

You probebly want to change to the parent element with the price... so use `(//div[@aria-label="Price trends are based on the Trulia Estimate"])[1]//../h3/div` as your xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'geckodriver.exe')
def get_trulia_estimate(address):
    driver.get('https://www.trulia.com/')
    print(address)
    element = (By.ID, 'homepageSearchBoxTextInput')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).send_keys(address)
    search_button = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-auto-test-id='searchButton']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(search_button)).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    find_trulia_estimate_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@aria-label="Price trends are based on the Trulia Estimate"])[1]').text
    print(find_trulia_estimate_text)

get_trulia_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651')
```

> 693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651
>   Trulia Estimate

If you use the xpath of the price the output is:

> 693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651
>   $1,735,031

Answer (score 0):

if you want try without beautifulsoup,

```
     if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Trulia Estimate')]").is_displayed():
           estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='home-details-summary']//h3/div')]").text
        else:
           print("Estimate is not found")

print(estimate)
```